# tiny MCE cut,copy,paste in Edit is not working in Chrome - Warning Message : KeyboardEvent.keyIdentifier' is deprecated

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, tinymce, rte

I am having a problem with the TinyMCE RTE.
Under Edit Menu, I have the options shown in the below screenshot.

[image]

Except "Select All" , no other option is working.
The code in the tinymce.min.js contains the following lines :

```
e.addButton("undo", { tooltip: "Undo", onPostRender: c, cmd: "undo" }),
e.addButton("redo", { tooltip: "Redo", onPostRender: u, cmd: "redo" }),
e.addMenuItem("undo", { text: "Undo", icon: "undo", shortcut: "Ctrl+Z", onPostRender: c, cmd: "undo" }),
e.addMenuItem("redo", { text: "Redo", icon: "redo", shortcut: "Ctrl+Y", onPostRender: u, cmd: "redo" }),
e.addMenuItem("visualaid", { text: "Visual aids", selectable: !0, onPostRender: d, cmd: "mceToggleVisualAid" }),
s({
            cut: ["Cut", "Cut", "Ctrl+X"],
            copy: ["Copy", "Copy", "Ctrl+C"],
            paste: ["Paste", "Paste", "Ctrl+V"],
            selectall: ["Select all", "SelectAll", "Ctrl+A"],
```

)}

Below are the lines of code which I am using when I initialize the RTE in my UI.

```
 var ed = new tinymce.Editor('myTxtArea', {
            menubar: 'edit insert view format table',
            plugins: ["paste autolink fullscreen table lists link image charmap print preview anchor code "],
            toolbar: "InsertTecDocLink | insertfile undo redo | bold italic |  underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | strikethrough | superscript | subscript |  code | bullist | numlist outdent indent | link  image | fontselect "
```

When I debug, I do see the Plugin for **Paste** being loaded.

Below warning is displayed in Chrome.

```
**'KeyboardEvent.keyIdentifier' is deprecated and will be removed in M53, around September 2016. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5316065118650368 for more details.**
```

But the Cut, Copy, Paste, Undo , Redo options are not working.

Please suggest where I might be going wrong.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What version of TinyMCE are you using?  The latest is 4.3.3 and I don't see any of these issues on that version with the latest Chrome browser.

Comment: I using the earlier version. I cannot upgrade it due to project dependencies.